# Direct product of two tables

Tags: database, storage

When is direct product of two tables useful? Seems like an academic thing.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are the uses for Cross Join?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/219716/what-are-the-uses-for-cross-join)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [What are the uses for cross join?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/219716/what-are-the-uses-for-cross-join)

Answer (score 2):

There are some uses for it. Let's say there is a clothing store selling T-Shirts in different colours and different sizes. Each combo has it's own SKU.

If there is a table Products that references tables Sizes and Colors then

You could get list of all possible products with:

```
SELECT * FROM Products, Colors, Sizes
```

Okay that is actually quite academic.

Comment: I just checked out 'What are the uses for cross join?' and there is also a color sizes example.

Answer (score 1):

Some times you want to get every possible combination of rows that match certain criteria. The way to do it is cross-join and then filter out rows that do not match the criteria.

Inner/Outer joins are just a special case of this: the desired criteria is "the data of table 1 is related to the data in table2..."