# let union show values beside each other instead of below each other

Tags: sql, sql-server

I got a SQL query which displays values out of two tables below each other. Now I want the table to select the values out of the two different tables besides each other. This is my query right now:

```
(select i1,i2 from t1
except
select i1,i2 from t2)
union all
(select i1,i2 from t2
except
select i1,i2 from t1)
```

This is my sample data:

Data I have in table1:

```
 i1   i2
---------
| 1 | 1 |
---------
| 2 | 2 |
---------
| 2 | 3 |
---------
```

data i have in table2:

```
 i1   i2
---------
| 1 | 1 |
---------
| 2 | 3 |
---------
| 2 | 4 |
---------
```

outcome:

```
---------
| 2 | 2 |  << this one comes from table 1
---------
| 2 | 4 |  << this one comes from table 2
---------
```

wanted outcome:

```
   t1      t2
-----------------
| 2 | 2 | 2 | 4 |
-----------------
```

Comment: That's called a "join".

Comment: That is not the purpose, or how a union works.  Use a join with a NOT EXISTS clause.

Comment: okay I see, sorry guys should I delete the question?

Comment: I don't think it's a bad question, it's just hard to follow your data examples, would be better if they had column headers probably.

Comment: Agreed with @HartCO on this one. You are just subject to some serial downvoters for asking basic questions, but the column header would have helped a lot.

Comment: This question is a total mystery with column names that mean anything.

Comment: @Hogan i updates the question with column names

Comment: Can you show us what would be the result if you add de record (2,6) in t1 and add the records (2,5),(2,7) in t2? Please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best way would be to use a `FULL JOIN` and then perform a `WHERE` with the `NULL` data. Because if you make a `CROSS JOIN` you would get more data than you need.

```
SELECT *
FROM t1
FULL JOIN t2
    ON t1.i1 = 2.i1
        AND t1.i2 = t2.i2
WHERE t1.Id IS NULL
    OR t2.Id IS NULL
```

I'll explain with an example:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#t1') IS NOT NULL
            DROP TABLE #t1

CREATE TABLE #t1
(
    Id INT IDENTITY,
    i1 INT,
    i2 INT
)

INSERT INTO #t1
(
    i1,i2
)
VALUES
(1,1)
,(2,2)
,(2,3)
,(2,6)

SELECT * FROM #t1

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#t2') IS NOT NULL
            DROP TABLE #t2

CREATE TABLE #t2
(
    Id INT IDENTITY,
    i1 INT,
    i2 INT
)

INSERT INTO #t2
(
    i1,i2
)
VALUES
(1,1)
,(2,3)
,(2,4)
,(2,5)
,(2,7)

SELECT * FROM #t2


SELECT *
FROM #t1
FULL JOIN #t2
    ON #t1.i1 = #t2.i1
        AND #t1.i2 = #t2.i2
WHERE #t1.Id IS NULL
    OR #t2.Id IS NULL

SELECT *
FROM #t1 a
CROSS JOIN #t2 b
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM #t2 c
                  WHERE a.i1 = c.i1 
                    AND a.i2 = c.i2
                  )
  AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM #t1 c
                  WHERE b.i1 = c.i1 
                    AND b.i2 = c.i2
                  )
```

**RESULT**

In the first case you would get 5 records because (2,2) and (2,6) do not exist in t2, and (2,4), (2,5), (2,7) do not exist in t1. So you would have 5 results.

```
Id          i1          i2          Id          i1          i2
----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- -----------
2           2           2           NULL        NULL        NULL
4           2           6           NULL        NULL        NULL
NULL        NULL        NULL        3           2           4
NULL        NULL        NULL        4           2           5
NULL        NULL        NULL        5           2           7

(5 row(s) affected)
```

However, in the CROSS JOIN you would get 6 results because you would make a Cartesian product. 2 x 3 = 6 [CROSS JOIN Explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/219716/what-are-the-uses-for-cross-join)

```
Id          i1          i2          Id          i1          i2
----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- -----------
2           2           2           3           2           4
2           2           2           4           2           5
2           2           2           5           2           7
4           2           6           3           2           4
4           2           6           4           2           5
4           2           6           5           2           7

(6 row(s) affected)
```

Comment: I thought of using a full join, but to get the '2,2' record on the same line as the '2,4' record you'd have to use `<>` and `OR`, and then you still have to filter unwanted lines using the `NOT EXIST`s.

Comment: @HartCO Thanks for your comment. I will check it!

Comment: @HartCO Yes, I agree with you. I asked the user to give us more details in case he added additional records. So I can see better what it is that you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a `CROSS JOIN` and `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT *
FROM t1 a
CROSS JOIN t2 b
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM t2 c
                  WHERE a.i1 = c.i1 
                    AND a.i2 = c.i2
                  )
  AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM t1 c
                  WHERE b.i1 = c.i1 
                    AND b.i2 = c.i2
                  )
```

A `CROSS JOIN` joins every record from one table with every record from the other, so every combination of rows is returned. `NOT EXISTS` is used to filter out records from `t1` that ever appear in `t2` and vice versa for the 2nd `NOT EXISTS`

Comment: That would return more records than needed if the user has much more data. I would make a Cartesian product that I do not think the user needs.

Comment: You might be underestimating the query optimizer, but I'd love to see an alternative that returns the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
SELECT *
FROM 
    (
        SELECT i1, i2
        FROM t1

        EXCEPT

        SELECT i1, i2
        FROM t2
    ) a, 
    (
        SELECT i1, i2
        FROM t2

        EXCEPT

        SELECT i1, i2
        FROM t1
    ) b
```

Comment: It returns the same result of CROSS JOIN, isn´t it?